# Cons of directly pushing .env file in Google Cloud Standard App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add environment variables in my App Engine Standard NodeJs app, and I have found multiple ways, out of which one is to add them in `app.yaml` using separate file(which we will not commit to repo), and second is to directly push `.env` file while deploying to App engine (Not ignoring it).

I was just thinking what are the cons of the second step which is to directly push my `.env` file(which I was also doing in App Engine Nodejs Flexible app)? Are there any major issues if I will do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no issue with it. You can consider it as your own server. No one will have access to your environments variables. So, it's safe.

Comment: Can google support people view it, coz in case of app.yaml variables are clearly visible to google support team which I do not want.

Comment: Your app.yaml file is visible but not your internal files I guess. Although I am not 100% sure as to what exactly is visible because privacy doesn't seem to list any information regarding this matter.